# PYTHON TKINTER - Trying to take in multiple entries in one window but the entry values aren't printing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button

So this is a snippet of my code below. I'm trying to take in 3 enteries (entry1, entry2, entry3) in one window (new_window1) and then once the user presses 'Submit' button, it's supposed to print the 3 entries but it doesn't seem to print anything. How can i fix this?

```
        var_lport= StringVar()
        var_rport= StringVar()
        var_server= StringVar()
        def autossh():
            new_window1 = Toplevel(my_window)
            new_window1.geometry("500x250")
            new_window1.title("")
            new_window1.config(bg="black")
            label3 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the local port number you wish to forward:", bg="black", fg="red")
            label3.pack()
            def return_value1():
                var_lport.set(entry1.get())
            entry1 = Entry(new_window1)
            entry1.pack()
            label4 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the remote port number you wish to forward to: ", bg="black", fg="red")
            label4.pack()
            def return_value2():
                var_rport.set(entry2.get())
            entry2 = Entry(new_window1)
            entry2.pack()
            label5 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the server you wish to connect to including the username: ", bg="black", fg="red")
            label5.pack()
            def return_value3():
                var_server.set(entry3.get())
            entry3 = Entry(new_window1)
            entry3.pack()

    
        

            button10 = Button(new_window1, text="Submit", width = 5, font="System 20", bg="red", fg="black", activebackground="black", activeforeground="red", borderwidth=5, cursor="hand2", highlightthickness=0, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", command=lambda: [return_value1(), return_value2(), return_value3(), new_window1.destroy()])
            button10.pack()
            new_window1.wait_variable(var_lport)
            new_window1.wait_variable(var_rport)
            new_window1.wait_variable(var_server)
            print(var_lport.get())
            print(var_rport.get())
            print(var_server.get())
```

Comment: There's no point in doing `wait_variable()` three times, when all three vars are set at the same time.  There's no point in having three separate `return_valueX()` functions, either.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it is better to use `.wait_window()` instead of three `.wait_variable()`.  Also it is better to use `textvariable` option of `Entry` widget to link the three tkinter variables to the three `Entry` widgets, then you don't need the three `return_valueX()` functions:

```py
var_lport= StringVar()
var_rport= StringVar()
var_server= StringVar()

def autossh():
    new_window1 = Toplevel(my_window)
    new_window1.geometry("500x250")
    new_window1.title("")
    new_window1.config(bg="black")

    label3 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the local port number you wish to forward:", bg="black", fg="red")
    label3.pack()
    entry1 = Entry(new_window1, textvariable=var_lport)
    entry1.pack()

    label4 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the remote port number you wish to forward to:", bg="black", fg="red")
    label4.pack()
    entry2 = Entry(new_window1, textvariable=var_rport)
    entry2.pack()

    label5 = Label(new_window1, text="Please enter the server you wish to connect to including the username:", bg="black", fg="red")
    label5.pack()
    entry3 = Entry(new_window1, textvariable=var_server)
    entry3.pack()

    button10 = Button(new_window1, text="Submit", width = 5, font="System 20",
                      bg="red", fg="black", activebackground="black", activeforeground="red",
                      borderwidth=5, cursor="hand2", highlightthickness=0, highlightcolor="black",
                      highlightbackground="black", command=new_window1.destroy)
    button10.pack()

    # wait for new_window1 to close
    new_window1.wait_window()
    # show the variable values
    print(var_lport.get())
    print(var_rport.get())
    print(var_server.get())
```